# Notice: undefined index with session global

Tags: php, arrays, session

I was adding a multi-language system to my website, but came accross this error. Everytime I try to set some value on my $_SESSION, it says

```
Notice: Undefined index: lang in ...\pages\lang.php on line 3
```

What I noticed, is when I'm trying to set the $_SESSION on my core file, it works, but if I'm trying to include the file which sets the session to the core file, it throws out that error. Here's the snippet of core.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
//some code
//if I type $_SESSION['lang'] = 'smth'; here, it will work
if (!isset($_GET['page']) || $_GET['page'] == "" || !file_exists('pages/'.$_GET['page'].'.php')) {
  include 'pages/home.php';
} else {
  include 'pages/'.$_GET['page'].'.php';
}
?>
```

pages/lang.php:

```
<?php
$lang = $_GET['lang'];
$_SESSION['lang'] == $lang;
var_dump($_SESSION); //prints an empty array ( array { } )
//header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: It looks as though `$_GET['lang']` is not defined.

Comment: Directly using a query parameter in an include directive is a hideously BAD idea - it allows remote users to include any file they want, just by modifying the url in their browser. At least you've got a `.php` extension enforced, but that still lets them include any .php file on your server, whether you want them to or not.

Comment: @Hammerite, it is defined in the URL.

Comment: @MarcB well, they can access any .php file by typing it's location/name in the address bar too, can't they? :) Anyways, I'm just in the alpha mode, I will make some restrictions(like removing '.' or '..' from it). Any more you could offer? Maybe I should do it in some other way?

Comment: @Tom: yes, but if they include paths in the query parameter ,they can get files from ANYWHERE on your server: `http://example.com/yourpage.php?page=../../../othersite/some_file_that_shouldnt_be_included`

Comment: @MarcB "I will make some restrictions(like removing '.' or '..' from it"

Comment: @Tom: regardless. Directly using user-provided data like this is a bad idea. Consider it the filesystem equivalent of an SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to include `session_start();` in the start of every script that uses the $_SESSION variables.

Also a typo: `$_SESSION['lang'] == $lang;` should be just one '='.

Comment: It is included, as I mentioned, if I set the session variable in the core file, it works.

Comment: I think he means that you need to start the session in `pages/lang.php` as well.

Comment: According to your code snippet, `pages/lang.php` does **not** use `session_start();`. As Dvir said, you have to include `session_start();` on _every_ script that uses session variables.

Comment: I do no run pages/lang.php, I include it from the core file, so it already has session_start(); Anyways, if do include it in that file, I get the error Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in ...\pages\lang.php on line 2.

Comment: @Tom: you also use == instead of =, unless that's ANOTHER missing or typo'd code in your question.... `$_SESSION['lang'] == $lang;`

Comment: Thanks man for pointing that out(2 equal signs). I can't believe I didn't notice that... :(